# Facebook app review error "The server refused the connection"

Tags: facebook, review

I submitted my app to facebook for review and i got back the following error:

"Canvas
When I try to load your app on Facebook (Canvas) page I see the following message: “The server refused the connection.” Can you please confirm that everything is working correctly with your test user and resubmit for review? Thanks."

I check the facebook canvas settings and i think that everything is ok (the app working just fine when i run it). Does anyone else had the same problem?

Facebook canvas:   https://apps.facebook.com/spacetiles
Secure Canvas URL: https://www.webcubes.eu/spacetiles/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been a connection issue when Facebook attempted to review the app.

f you are confident that the app works and that no firewall settings are blocking Facebook from reviewing the app then you should go ahead and resubmit it for review.

Comment: I submitted twice and i had the same answer. Does the links work for you? The facebook team probably check th second one.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the correct canvas URL. Remove the second link and resubmit. You should get approved this time.